# How can I import an encrypted database in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, import

I'm trying to import a Database dump file that someone else made but i keep getting an error message.

i've tried uploading from the command line and from PHPMyAdmin but neither seem to work.

mysql -u root -p new_db < db_dump.sql

ERROR 3185 (HY000) at line 25: Can't find master key from keyring, please check in the server log if a keyring plugin is loaded and initialized successfully.

Answer (score 4):

Open the .sql file with any code editor and find then delete all occurrences for ENCRYPTION='Y' that you see in the .sql file dump.

Both Mysql and MariaDB are now able to import the .sql file.